# "...и все тут" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Это он(,) и все тут". Не могу понять: это сложное предложение или простое? Нужна запятая после "он"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Это он, и всё тут". Запятая нужна, т.к. предложение сложное. Первое простое двусоставное, а второе относится к словам-предложениям, выражающим эмоциональную оценку предшествующего высказывания, так называемое междометное предложение типа "И баста". Возможно расценить и как эллиптическое предложение с пропуском сказуемого(сказано, ясно),  смысл  которого  понятен без контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, так как слово"все" написано через букву "е". Если здесь, действительно, буква "е", то запятая, естественно, не нужна, так как речь идет об однородных членах. Если же "всё" (скорее всего, именно так написано), то запятая необходима, так как это сложное предложение.